# xslt 1.0 - display only one distinct value in a table cell as part of a multi-column table and alternate colors

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an xml file that has some data that is being output in a table split into two columns (effectively). This is the XML

```
<structuredBody>
  <component>
    <section>
      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1" />
      <entry>
        <organizer>
          <component>
            <observation>
              <code displayName="TIBC" />
              <effectiveTime value="8/29/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
              <value value="39" />
              <referenceRange>
                <observationRange>
                  <text />
                </observationRange>
              </referenceRange>
            </observation>
          </component>
        </organizer>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <organizer>
          <component>
            <observation>
              <code displayName="TSAT" />
              <effectiveTime value="8/29/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
              <value value="25" />
              <referenceRange>
                <observationRange>
                  <text />
                </observationRange>
              </referenceRange>
            </observation>
          </component>
        </organizer>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <organizer>
          <component>
            <observation>
              <code displayName="Albumin" />
              <effectiveTime value="9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
              <value value="46" />
              <referenceRange>
                <observationRange>
                  <text />
                </observationRange>
              </referenceRange>
            </observation>
          </component>
        </organizer>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <organizer>
          <component>
            <observation>
              <code displayName="ALT" />
              <effectiveTime value="9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
              <value value="48" />
              <referenceRange>
                <observationRange>
                  <text>21-72</text>
                </observationRange>
              </referenceRange>
            </observation>
          </component>
        </organizer>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <organizer>
          <component>
            <observation>
              <code displayName="Bicarbonate" />
              <effectiveTime value="9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
              <value value="69" />
              <referenceRange>
                <observationRange>
                  <text />
                </observationRange>
              </referenceRange>
            </observation>
          </component>
        </organizer>
      </entry>
    </section>
  </component>
  <component>
    <section>
      <...>
    </section>
  </component>
  <component>
    <section>
      <...>
    </section>
  </component>
</structuredBody>
```

I've got the output formatted using xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="//section[templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1']!=''">
        <xsl:variable name="rowLabs" select="ceiling(count(//section[templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1']/entry) div $colLabs)" />

        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Lab Results:</span>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="99%" style="font-size: 11px;">
                <xsl:for-each select="//section[templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1']/entry[position() &lt;= $rowLabs]">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:variable name="otherEntries" select=".|following-sibling::entry[position() mod $rowLabs = 0]" />
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|$otherEntries" />
                        <xsl:call-template name="blankentries">
                            <xsl:with-param name="entries" select="$colLabs - count($otherEntries) - 1" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::entry[position() &lt; 2]" />-->
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1']/entry">
    <td width="75">
        <xsl:call-template name="StripTime">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </td>
    <td width="198">
        <xsl:value-of select="organizer/component/observation/code/@displayName"/>
    </td>
    <td width="50">
        <xsl:value-of select="organizer/component/observation/value/@value"/>
    </td>
    <td width="75">
        <xsl:value-of select="organizer/component/observation/referenceRange/observationRange/text"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="blankentries">
    <xsl:param name="entries" />
    <xsl:if test="$entries > 0">
        <td></td>
        <xsl:call-template name="blankentries">
            <xsl:with-param name="entries" select="$entries - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

so that the resulting entry nodes run down and then over so that the output is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>8/29/2013</td>
    <td>TIBC</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9/5/2013</td>
    <td>ALT</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>21-72</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8/29/2013</td>
    <td>TSAT</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9/5/2013</td>
    <td>Bicarbonate</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9/5/2013</td>
    <td>Albumin</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This gives me:

```
[entry 1] [entry 4]
[entry 2] [entry 5]
[entry 3]
```

which is what I'm looking for and that's great.

What I can't figure out is how to get the different 4-cell entry sets to alternate colors as it goes through. I can't use position() because I'm manipulating it to get the desired output order in the table. If I output the position to figure out the math, on the left column, it's always "1" and on the right column it's always "2" so I can't do a position() mod 2 = 1 to set a style attribute.

Secondly, I only want the date value to appear one time and then not appear until it changes. That would make it such that the output ideally should look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>8/29/2013</td>
    <td>TIBC</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td></td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc"></td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc">ALT</td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc">48</td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc">21-72</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc"></td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc">TSAT</td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc">25</td>
    <td bgcolor="dcdcdc"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Bicarbonate</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9/5/2013</td>
    <td>Albumin</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can't put the bgcolor attribute in the "tr" tag because it should alternate even across the "columns" and not just the entire row.

Thanks for any help. This site has brought my xslt knowledge a long way. I've only started delving into it in the last month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the colours you essentially have two cases depending on whether `$rowLabs` is odd or even.

- If it's even then odd rows will be entirely "white" and even rows will be entirely "black"
- If it's odd then

  - for odd rows, odd columns will be white and even ones black
  - for even rows, odd columns will be black and even ones white

("odd" and "even" counting from 1 as XPath `position()` does, so the first row/column is odd, the second is even, etc.).

You can encode that logic in XSLT by adding some parameters to the templates.  Replace the

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|$otherEntries" />
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|$otherEntries">
    <xsl:with-param name="rowNum" select="position()" />
    <xsl:with-param name="totalRows" select="$rowLabs" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and add the parameters to the `section` template

```
<xsl:template match="section[templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.3.1']/entry">
    <xsl:param name="rowNum" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="totalRows" select="2" />
```

Now we need a named template we can call to implement the logic I described above:

```
<xsl:template name="bgcolor">
    <xsl:param name="rowNum" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="totalRows" select="2" />
    <xsl:if test="($totalRows mod 2 = 0 and $rowNum mod 2 = 0) or
                  ($totalRows mod 2 = 1 and $rowNum mod 2 != position() mod 2)">
        <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">dcdcdc</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This adds the `bgcolor` attribute if either there is an even number of rows and the current rownum is even, or if there is an odd number of rows and the current *column* number within the row has a "different oddness" from the row number.

Finally we call this template within the `<td>` elements, e.g.

```
<td width="50">
    <xsl:call-template name="bgcolor">
        <xsl:with-param name="rowNum" select="$rowNum" />
        <xsl:with-param name="totalRows" select="$totalRows" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="organizer/component/observation/value/@value"/>
</td>
```

The crucial thing that makes all this work is the fact that you're applying templates to `self::*|$otherEntries`, so a call to `position()` within the applied template gives the column number (the position within this node list), not the node's original position in its parent.

---

To make the date appear only once the first time it is encountered, you can define a *key* and use a trick related to the "Muenchian grouping" technique.  Declare

```
<xsl:key name="effectiveTimeByDate" match="effectiveTime"
         use="substring-before(@value, ' ')" />
```

and then you can check whether this is the first occurrence of a particular date in the document using

```
<td width="75">
    <xsl:call-template name="bgcolor">
        <xsl:with-param name="rowNum" select="$rowNum" />
        <xsl:with-param name="totalRows" select="$totalRows" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:if test="
         generate-id(organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime)
       = generate-id(key('effectiveTimeByDate', substring-before(
            organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value, ' '))[1])">
        <xsl:call-template name="StripTime">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="organizer/component/observation/effectiveTime/@value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</td>
```

(you may be able to scrap the `StripTime` template entirely and just use the `substring-before` call the same as I'm using in the key)

Comment: So how do I pass that into the xsl:template where I'm building the table cells? I know I can't use a variable that I manipulate the value of (like I would in a .NET application) based on a condition.

Comment: @jjasper0729 sorry, I was mid-edit, does it make more sense now?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. I WILL get the hang of this. It's a big change in thinking from going from .NET programming to how XSLT processes things. That works great for the alternating colors. Now all I need to do is figure out how to get the repeating dates not to show up (per the desired table output in the question)

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. I know I'm not well versed in XSLT coding so now I need to delve into the "why" and not just the "how" so I can get this to be second nature. It's a big change from sub-routine and function calls of .NET. Thanks for all your help.